# Weyl-Minkowski V-H representation of a cone, with Kronecker products

Tags: matrices, reference-request, convex-analysis, kronecker-product, convex-cone

**Conjecture**. If the $V$ cone generated by the points in the matrix $A$ has an $H$ representation captured by matrix $B$, and $A = A_1 \otimes A_2$, $B = B_1 \otimes B_2$, where $B_1$ is the $H$ representation of the cone generated by the points in $A_1$, and $B_2$ is the $H$ representation of the cone generated by the points in $A_2$, $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product; then the $B$ cone generated by the points in $A_1 \otimes A_2$, has an $H$ representation with matrix $B_1 \otimes B_2$.

---

Do you know if someone has established this conjecture to be true?

Please do take into account this is a generalization of the Weyl-Minkowski theorem. I am asking for a paper or book where you think I could find it. Apologies if this kind of question is not allowed. I have done the $2 \times 2$ case and it works. But not sure about the general problem.

Answer (score 0):

So this is fully solved in

- Guillaume Aubrun, Ludovico Lami, Carlos Palazuelos, Martin Plavala, [Entangleability of cones](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.09663), 2019-2021.

The proposition is only true if and only if one of the cones is a simplex

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2058112)